# Contextual ActionBar for ListView With checkbox

Tags: android, android-listview, contextual-action-bar

I'm working with ListActivity with checkbox, I want to initiate Contextual Action Bar from the listview whenever the list item is checked and show the number items that are selected. I have gone through the CAB from http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html#CAB . But I still have difficulty understanding where should I invoke the CAB?